# Random Field in 4 button

Tags: android

Can you tell me how to random field of button.

```
b1.setText(question.getOption1());
b2.setText(question.getOption2());
b3.setText(question.getOption3());
b4.setText(question.getOption4());
```

how to b1 have a rondom `getOption()` and b2,b3,b4 too ?

Comment: Hi Gyroth, please elaborate your question in detail.

Comment: I want to create random button text, so the text of button b1,b2,b3,and b4 have random field from getOption1,2,3,and 4.

Comment: how do you gettting these values ? explain in detail

Comment: You need to implement a shuffle using a `List` with your `getOption()`.

Comment: you can shuffle your option list like Collections.shuffle(optionList);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have list of options, you can try something like this:

```java
List<String> optionList=new ArrayList<>();
optionList.add("option a");
optionList.add("option b");
optionList.add("option c");
optionList.add("option d");

Collections.shuffle(optionList);

b1.setText(optionList.get(0));
b2.setText(optionList.get(1));
b3.setText(optionList.get(2));
b4.setText(optionList.get(3));
```